# pushbots-cli not recognized but installed windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, file-not-found, pushbots

I have no idea where to go with this.
I spent 3 days searching solution for this issue

I installed pushbots-cli (through npm) but i cant get it working.
Getting "'pushbots' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

searched all over the net. Gave up.
Please help if you had such problem. 
I can use cordova and phonegap plugin (using command line) but not pushbots itself.

I did settled it on Mac, but not on windows.

(node installed, python, node-gyp as well)

very big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps....this is what I did.

Install python: http://www.python.org/getit/windows/
Install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 Express version: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816758

Install node-gyp: `npm install -g node-gyp`
Then run `npm install -g pushbots-cli` in the terminal
Type `pushbots --help` to ensure it is installed

Also make sure node and npm are installed.

Comment: tryed! all installed, but on windows it makes problems (